# Can I test a controller method from a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a website built in ASP.NET MVC that uses an XML file as the backbone for its menu system.  The nodes in that XML file list the menu items, their display text, and the controller name and action method that is called.  I came up with an idea that if I could call a controller method with the controller name and action method name I could programmatically test all of the methods to see if they throw errors.  I don't want to display the page in the browser; just run the controller method and any errors will be logged in my database.  I would like to do it with something like this code from a Test model class, but I can't get this to compile yet.  The RenderAction is a method that is working in my View pages, but the model says that method doesn't exist.  Can somebody guide me how to get this to work?

```
HtmlHelper oHtmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(oViewContext, oViewDataContainer);
oHtmlHelper.RenderAction(sController, sAction);
```

Comment: A few questions: Why are you trying to test the controller in the model?  Is there a reason why you're not testing your controller methods in a unit test class? Also, what are the error or errors you're receiving when you try to compile?

Comment: Why not in a unit test class?  Because I don't know how to do that.  If I can do that using my XML file to quickly iterate the nodes I'm interested in learning more.  If I have to build a complex unit testing structure like I've seen at other companies, then I'm not interested.  We're looking for a simpler solution or it won't get done.

Comment: I found the errors and I was able to get it to compile and run.  It works beautifully.  Look at all the down votes I have gotten.  I would post my solution here, but not with that kind of abuse.  You guys are so closed minded.  You can only see the "enterprise way" of doing things.  My approach is brilliant.  Thanks for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of testing is to drive you to better, more maintainable code. Part of that is unit testing, which by nature, tests discreet *units* of functionality. What you have here is a situation that is absolute begging to be refactored. When things are difficult to test, that's a sure sign that your design is flawed.

Instead of having all this logic in an action, and then attempt to test the whole action rendering logic to determine if it's working or not, break out the logic into a helper class. Then, you should be able to easily test whether a method in that class returns a good result.

I'm not sure what you mean by "complex unit testing structure", as unit tests are inherently simple and pretty much everything you need is baked into .NET (although better options often exist as third-party libraries). Regardless, all you need to get started unit testing is to create a unit test project, add a reference to the project you want to test on, and then add a simple class like:

```
[TestClass]  
public class MyAwesomeTests
{  
    [TestMethod]  
    public void TestSomething()  
    {
        ...
    }  
}
```